# Jquery / .Net Passing a Server Variable in the Data of Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, server-variables

I want to take a .Net server variable and user that in the data of an Ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "get_user_info.aspx",
  data: "user_id=<%=UserID%>" 
});
```

However, I get an Object Expected error with the above.

The UserID is an int in the C# codebehind.

I have tried casting it to string like this:

```
var useridstring = <%=UserID%>;
var mynewstring = useridstring.toString();

 $.ajax({
      url: "get_user_info.aspx",
      data: {user_id:mynewstring} 
    });
```

It is not working though. I've read posts here about using a hidden input with a variable, but I am hoping to avoid that method if something like the above can work.

Comment: In the second case: 1. what is the value of `useridstring` *and*, 2. in what way is it "not working"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your field name (user_id) needs to be a string:

```
var useridstring = '<%=UserID%>';


 $.ajax({
      url: "get_user_info.aspx",
      data: {'user_id':useridstring} 
    });
```

Comment: Technically, the field name doesn't have to be a string, unless you're doing something odd with it (like passing an array).  But your code DOES fix the problem, because of the first line - without the quotes around <%=UserID%>, javascript will try to evaluate whatever the UserID is as a variable, instead of a string.

Comment: Hmm... Still not working. I still get a Javascript error Object Expected any time I put in <%=UserID%> anywhere. If I take it out, it works fine. I put it in and the JS further down the page freaks out. I am using .Net 2.0 framework with ViewState. Could there be a conflict anywhere in there?

Comment: Can you please post your HTML (not your .net source): jsfiddle.net

Comment: So I ended up having to do the hidden field workaround. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would place the variable inside a hidden div and get from jquery the inner text of this div.

```
var useridstring = $get('myDiv');

<div id='myDiv' style="display:none;><%:UserID%></div>
```

Comment: yes, Diodeus gave the correct answer, actually my solution do not help solving the issue...